# OSX Terminal find regex for jpg JPG and jpeg

Tags: regex, terminal, find

```
find ./ -name '*.JPG' -type f | wc -l
```

gives me `1231` and

```
find ./ -name '*.jpg' -type f | wc -l
```

gives `1377`

How can I do a regex to find all JPGs ?

I've tried

```
find ./ -type f -regex ".*\.[JPGjpg]$" | wc -l
```

but nothing also similar works

Comment: What about `find ./ -type f -regex ".*\.[Jj][Pp][gG]$" | wc -l`?

Comment: How about `find ./ -iname '*.jpg' -type f | wc -l`? (Note that you can't *quite* rely on `wc -l` to give you the number of files found; filenames *may* contain newlines, although it's rare.)

Comment: You can use `-printf` to print something else than the filename to reliably create one line of output per file for `wc -l`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is hosed.  But by using a different option, it can be simplified to be a lot less complex / intimidating.

```
find . -E -type f -iregex '.*\.jpe?g'
```

Square brackets create a character class -- `[JPG|jpg]` matches a single character which is one of J, P, G, or vertical bar (yes, everything between  the square brackets is taken literally) in upper or lower case. Use round parentheses for grouping; although this is simple enough to not require any grouping. Note also the use of `-iregex` to make a case-insensitive regex match.

As noted in comments, on e.g. MacOS / BSD the `-E` option is necessary to enable ERE constructs like `?` for marking an expression as optional.

Comment: seems like! first regex I've tried to write. Your's better but what if `JPG` hasn't got an `E` or `e` ?

Comment: I think case-insensitive `iregex` is easier, isn't it? `find -E . -type f -iregex '.*jpe?g'`

Comment: the regex before update still didn't work, there was a missing `)` but also with it it didn't work.. liked the example though

Comment: I think you need the `-E` on a Mac too... it doesn't work on mine without as it doesn't interpret the regex as an extended one without.